# Finding a decent Development Team

Tags: software-development, development-process, team

hope this isn't out of the concept, I couldn't find any place better to ask. Me and my friend are working on a social networking app idea but we both don't know enough coding to develop that big of an app. We decided to hire a development team, approximately around 5-10 developers, which has developers for both frontend and backend development, and also which has designers for UI design and stuff. The problem is, I've been trying to find such team on oDesk and Elance but I can't trust those people, I don't know why. I have limited budget (enough for a prototype app, then I'm planning to try to get some investment or loan). Do any of you know a decent development team that fulfills my qualifications? Or can any of you give me some advice on what should I do? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recruiting for a specific task; the answer is not useful to other members of the forum.

Comment: @Mark, don't we hire for specific tasks for projects?

Comment: (a) Although we may, the experience is generally not transferable; I cannot learn from the way you do it, and you can't learn from the way I do it (arguable, but I believe true)  (b) This question is more like a software recommendation; "do you know a software development team that fulfills **my qualifications**, not "What are good principles for recruiting?"  (c) the question is too specific.  I'll stop here; although I intended to clarify my objection, I fear I may have stepped over the line and am arguing in comments.

Comment: Understand your points.  Maybe the question can be improved to make it more suitable.  I think one of the biggest things to learn around hiring is that the tribal beliefs and knowledge that continue to get passed down on selection techniques are a systemic weakness cutting across all industries, professions and trades, and job families.

Comment: PMSE is not a recruiting agency or referral engine, and such questions are not within the scope defined by our Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of hiring.  What you are essentially trying to do here is to predict future performance using indicators that have very low to no predictive validity.  Stronger predictors are expensive to develop and use and, therefore, used minimally.  And you will find that a lot of hiring managers truly believe in their ability to sift through a pool of candidates using their powerful interviewing skills so not a lot of real analysis is done around how to hire better.  We continue to rely heavily on this notion of experience, degrees, certificates, and our interview skills.

The bottom line is, there really is no great answer to your question.  Hiring is full of risk.  It sounds like you do not have the money or time to really do this well so sift through the candidates you have, try to tease out the smartest of them, find the ones you think you can get a long with the best, try to reduce your biases, and then be quick to cut bait at the first signs of low performance.  Don't throw good money after bad.  But set your expectations properly.  Most likely, you will find mediocre to average performance and maybe you will get one or two you can really rely on.  This is what most of us live with everyday on our teams.  This the result of the performance distribution.